# How to search for more than two keywords?

Tags: php, pdo, axios

I have 5 field name the `first_name`, `last_name`, `middle_name`, `status` and `barangay_name`, I want to search for data depending on the user want. The problem only the last field name which is the `barangay_name` is working fine. The rest is not, what is wrong with my query? I only retrieve the active beneficiary and I inner join the `tbl_beneficiary` and `tbl_barangay`.

```
  public function searchActiveBeneficiary($keyword) {
        $sql = "SELECT tbl_beneficiary.beneficiary_id, 
        tbl_beneficiary.first_name, tbl_beneficiary.last_name, 
        tbl_beneficiary.middle_name, tbl_beneficiary.is_active, 
        tbl_barangay.barangay_name FROM tbl_beneficiary INNER JOIN tbl_barangay 
        ON tbl_barangay.barangay_id = tbl_beneficiary.barangay_id WHERE 
        tbl_beneficiary.is_active = 'Yes' AND tbl_beneficiary.first_name OR 
        tbl_beneficiary.is_active = 'Yes' AND tbl_beneficiary.last_name OR 
        tbl_beneficiary.is_active = 'Yes' AND tbl_beneficiary.middle_name OR 
        tbl_beneficiary.is_active = 'Yes' AND tbl_barangay.barangay_name LIKE 
        :keyword";

        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute([
            ":keyword" => '%' . $keyword . '%'
        ]);

        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }

  //vue.js method
  searchActiveBeneficiary : function() {
        axios({
            method : "GET",
            url : this.urlRoot + "beneficiary/search_active_beneficiary.php?keyword=",
            params : {
                keyword : this.search_active_beneficiary
            }
        }).then(function (response){
            vm.active_beneficiaries = response.data;
            console.log(response);
        });
    },

  <?php

    include '../../private/initialize.php';

    $beneficiary = new Beneficiary();

    echo json_encode($beneficiary->searchActiveBeneficiary($_GET['keyword']));

  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `barangay_name` is the only one which you are actually comparing with the keyword. You need to add the `LIKE` part of the expression to each of your conditions. Note that specifying `tbl_beneficiary.is_active = 'Yes'` more than once is unnecessary, you can just change the logic of your `WHERE` condition to give the same effect:

```
WHERE tbl_beneficiary.is_active = 'Yes'
  AND (tbl_beneficiary.first_name LIKE :keyword OR 
       tbl_beneficiary.last_name LIKE :keyword OR 
       tbl_beneficiary.middle_name LIKE :keyword OR 
       tbl_barangay.barangay_name LIKE :keyword)
```